# How can I query with a field parameter on a subrelation in Graphene-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-sqlalchemy

I am trying to figure out how I can accept a parameter and query on that field in a sub table in a GraphQL.

This is an example.

```
query{
  allModels{
    edges{
      node{
        featureVectors(featureSize: 128){ #I want to query on this
          edges{
            node{
              modelSize
              featureVectors
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is that I'm using to query the data. It works to query the data, except that I would like to be able to pass a parameter to search for a specific for example, featureVectors(featureSize: 128). I can't seem to find anything in the Graphene-SQLAlchemy library to allow this natively.

```
class ModelModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'models'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('models_id_seq'::regclass)"))
    type = Column(Text)
    components = Column(Float)
    notes = Column(Text)
    feature_vectors = relationship("FeatureVector", back_populates='models')

class FeatureVectorModel(Base):

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, server_default=text("nextval('feature_vectors_id_seq'::regclass)"))
    model_size = Column(Integer)
    feature_vectors = Column(ARRAY(Float(precision=53)))

    models = relationship('Model', back_populates='feature_vectors')

class Model(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )


class ModelConn(relay.Connection):
    class Meta:
        node = Model


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    node = relay.Node.Field(schema_cadlearn.Model)
    all_models = SQLAlchemyConnectionField(ModelConn)
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I am in the same boat, cant figure out how to do this..

Comment: @Phillip unfortunately I did not. I don’t think it’s possible and don’t know how to resolve it.